# Nextjs, metadata in client layout.tsx component

Tags: next.js, layout, server, client, metadata

in my nextjs web app i needed to make my main layout.tsx file a client component trough "use client", so i had to remove the export of the metadata object in order to make the app continuing work, but i need and want my homepage to be filled with its title on the tab as the metadata did, but as you could know it's not possible in client components, so my question is: how can i add a title to my homepage without metadata in my main layout file which for needs has become client component?

Comment: solved with title tag in my page.tsx at the top of the rendering jsx: <title>Page title</title>

Answer (score 0):

I don't find the solution to set the metadata through client component. But, you could separate the client side from layout.tsx into separate component like the example below.

layout.tsx

```js
import { Metadata } from 'next'
import Client from './Client'

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: 'Foo'
};

export default function RootLayout({
  children
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  return (
    <html lang='en'>
      <body>
        <Client>
          {children}
        </Client>
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

Client.tsx

```js
'use client'

export default function Client({
  children
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  return (
    <div>
      {children}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Metadata objects exported from multiple segments in the same route are shallowly merged together to form the final metadata output of a route. Duplicate keys are replaced based on their ordering.

app/layout.js

```js
    export const metadata = {
    title: 'Acme',
    openGraph: {
      title: 'Acme',
      description: 'Acme is a...',
      },
    }
```

app/page.js

```js
    export const metadata = { 
    title: 'Home',
    openGraph: {
      title: 'Home',
      },
    }
```

Output metadata : app/page.js

```js
    // <title>Home</title>
    // <meta property="og:title" content="Home" />
```

The layout page metadata will rewriten by page file. You can check the solution in the [docs here](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/optimizing/metadata#merging)